# Converting a sequence diagram into a communication diagram in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm using enterprise architect and I want to know if there's a way to convert a sequence diagram into a communication diagram.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no automated process built into [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com) to achieve this but I believe it is penciled in for a future release?

However here are a couple of workarounds:

The first, depending on what elements you have used to create your sequence diagram (use objects not lifelines), is to reuse the same elements. Create a new collaboration diagram and drag the sequence elements from the Project Browser onto it. These will be exactly the same elements in both diagrams (so any name or attribute changes to one will be reflected in the other.

The second is to use Enterprise Architects [Automation Interface or scripting engine](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/automation_and_scripts/automation_interface.html) to write a quick script that will do it for you. I remember one of this being available in the past, but you had to contact support@sparxsystems.com to get them to send you a copy.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

RSA IBM and Omondo EclipseUML have this feature.